# Why onChanges is not triggered after update

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following parent component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'hello-world',
    template: `
    <div>
        <private [text]="value"></private>
    </div>`
})

export class HelloWorldComponent {
    public value: number = 3;

    constructor() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.value = 5;
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

And child component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'private',
    template: `<span>{{text}}</span>`
})

export class PrivateComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() public text: string;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        console.log(changes.text.currentValue);
    }
}
```

The `ngOnChanges` is triggered only once with the expected value of `3`, but it's not triggered second time with the value of `5`. Why?

Comment: Use arrow function `setTimeout(() => {`

Comment: @yurzui, silly me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are changing the value to `5`, `this` refers to the anonymous function you pass to `setTimeout` and not to your HelloWorldComponent instance, you can change the constructor to something like this:

```
constructor() {
    var _self = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        _self.value = 5;
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: yeah, thanks, or arrow function, or use `bind`, focused too much on `OnChanges` and forgot that part)

Comment: Indeed, those will do it too